# Azure Devops Migrate from TFVC to Git

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

I try to migrate from tfvc to git like the picture1.
[image]

but nothing comes into git repository like the picture2.

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the feature at the moment, I saw a few internal emails on this topic as well, I added this post. My recommendation would be to raise it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=21 or raise an Azure Support ticket https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511.

Comment: Hi, Product team has fixed the issue, let's wait a moment to use this feature to Migrate the TFVC repo to Git repo. By the way, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TFVC -> Git Import results in an empty repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448016/tfvc-git-import-results-in-an-empty-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reproduce this issue and we have reported this issue, you could refer to this [ticket](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Feature-to-import-code-from-TFVC-repo-to/1343967) to get the latest news.

As a workaround, we could migrate the TFVC repo to Git via git cmd.

let’s follow the migration guide and execute the clone command:

```
git tfs clone {TFVC repo URL}
```

Get all branches:

```
git tfs branch –init --all
```

For each branch, run these commands:

```
git checkout branch

git log -1

git tfs pull -c=changesetNumber
```

Create a new repo in the azure devops and get the repo URL. Then setup the git repository upstream:

```
git remote add origin {New repo URL}
```

Finally you push all your local changes to the Remote.

```
git push origin -u -all
```

We could refer to [MIGRATING FROM TFVC TO GIT](https://blog.cellenza.com/devops/migrating-from-tfvc-to-git/) and [Migrate From TFVC To Git](https://www.scrum-tips.com/agile/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/) for more details.

**Update1**

According to the latest news: A fix for this issue has been prepared. We’ll update you when it’s available.