# TFVC -> Git Import results in an empty repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfvc

Are  imports broken as of 3/2/21?

I tried the import process several times today in different AzDO projects and each time I get an empty git repo upon completion of the migration.

I did see there was an issue associated with repo performance degradation and waited until it was resolved: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/230197872

Permissions are not an issue. I attempted with elevated permissions and another user attempted as well.

Tried with and without history migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reproduce this issue on our side and we have reported this issue on our Developer Community forum, you could refer to this [ticket](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot--Migrate-from-TFVC-to-Git-via-UI/1354303?from=email&space=21&entry=myfeedback) to get the latest news.

As a workaround, we could migrate the TFVC repo to Git via git cmd.

Follow the migration guide and execute the clone command:

```
git tfs clone {TFVC repo URL}
```

Get all branches:

```
git tfs branch –init --all
```

For each branch, run these commands:

```
git checkout branch

git log -1

git tfs pull -c=changesetNumber
```

Create a new repo in the azure devops and get the repo URL. Then setup the git repository upstream:

```
git remote add origin {New repo URL}
```

Finally you push all your local changes to the Remote.

```
git push origin -u -all
```

You could refer to this [blog](https://blog.cellenza.com/devops/migrating-from-tfvc-to-git/) and [document](https://www.scrum-tips.com/agile/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/) for more details.